# How is baggage saved in a PNR by Amadeus

Tags: amadeus

On a website I can book flights. The booking itself seems to have no issues, but whenever I try to display my booking some part of the booking isn't show: more specific the baggage isn't shown correctly.

When I look into what the bookend returns, is seems to save baggage information in the SSR sections.

Is this correct?

Comment: The question isn't clear. Please provide some more details, code, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any code. All the work is done by 3rd party web service.

Comment: I'm basically trying to figure out how baggage is being stored at the PNR -leverl, in the hope I can make more sense of the question I'm being asked.

Answer (score 0):

It can be stored in the SSR, however, that's not reliable as it does not apply to all airlines.

Baggage information is stored in the TST services, not the PNR. Ticket_DisplayTST returns the baggage information for a booked PNR as it is related to the fare.

Comment: For offers though, it's not found in the `PNR_RetrieveAndDisplayReply.offerGroup`s as one would expect. I say this because the XML structure has an element for it which it is never used. Instead you have to get each `productPricingQuotationRecord` from each group with the `Ticket_GetQuotationDetails` service call, which sometimes amounts to a lot of calls. You could say it's the same as getting the TST data with the `Ticket_DisplayTST` call, but at least you get all of them in one go.

Comment: @Heki, offers does not apply to this as it's a booked PNR

Comment: indeed. I would have written an answer instead of a comment if I didn't realise that.